# Why does my visual call a measure that's not being used?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a power bi report with two pages `p1` and `p2`.
In `p1` I'm using measure `m1` to calculate a share for the country in visual `v1`. When creating `p2` the page was simply duplicated and the measure in `v2` was being replaced for `m2`. `m2` does not reference `m1`.

When I look at the dax query in **dax studio** for `v2`, `m1` is still being executed, although it is nowhere to be found in the graphical user interface of **power bi** desktop and `p2`. The query looks something like this (modified pseudocode):

```
// DAX Query
DEFINE
    MEASURE 'table_name'[m1] = 
        (/* USER DAX BEGIN */
dax_for_m1
/* USER DAX END */)

    MEASURE 'table_name2'[m2] = 
        (/* USER DAX BEGIN */
dax_for_m2
/* USER DAX END */)



    VAR __DS0FilterTable = 
        FILTER(
            KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('table_name'[some_date_var])),
            AND(
                'table_name'[some_date_var] >= DATE(2014, 1, 1),
                'table_name'[some_date_var] < (DATE(2024, 1, 31) + TIME(0, 0, 1))
            )
        )

    VAR __DS0FilterTable2 = 
        FILTER(
            KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('table_name'[some_identifier])),
            NOT(ISBLANK('table_name'[some_identifier]))
        )

    VAR __DS0FilterTable3 = 
        FILTER(
            KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('table_name2'[some_identifier])),
            NOT(ISBLANK('table_name2'[some_identifier]))
        )

    VAR __DS0FilterTable4 = 
        FILTER(
            KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('table_name3'[some_identifier])),
            NOT(ISBLANK('table_name3'[some_identifier]))
        )

EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        __DS0FilterTable,
        __DS0FilterTable2,
        __DS0FilterTable3,
        __DS0FilterTable4,
        "m1", IGNORE('table_name'[m1]),
        "m2", IGNORE('table_name2'[m2])
    )
```

If I recreate `v2`, from the ground up by selecting the same visual and adding `m2`, `m1` is no longer being called.

Is this a bug or is `m1` being stuck somewhere I don't know about?
I can't recreate this behaviour generally, in another report, only for the this specific report.

Comment: It is most likely that `m1` is still present in the Filters pane on the right-hand side, of the visual. Have a look in there.

Comment: If I look under filters/Filters on this visual, there is only `m1`is (All). The filters pane looks identical when I recreate `v2` from the ground up.

Comment: But `m1` is present in the filter pane for `v2` regardless of it being set to `All`. Not sure I understand your last sentence of the filter pane looking identical when you recreate `v2` from the ground up - how? Does the recreated `v2` have `m1` in the Filter pane?

Comment: Sorry, meant `m2`is (All). It feels like `m1` is being hidden in some setting like **data label**, but I just can't find it..

Comment: Could also be hidden in a Conditional Formatting rule.

Comment: Spot on, that was it! Thank you. Am pretty new to pbi and it was quite hard to discover just by browsing all the settings.